# how to change dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, netcat

I am trying to host a game server and it holds Netcat as a missing dependency despite having netcat-traditional. Is there a way to change the dependency to see and use the traditional variant?

Comment: Also see: https://serverfault.com/a/383958/229499, but this method isn't sustainable

Comment: You've provided few specifics, no OS & release details nor clues as to the actual issue. Depends rules can ensure you don't have *segfaults* or data corruption due to ABI/API changes that occur between releases; though on occasion issues are just due to newer versions that may not impact your intended use. To ensure no corruption of data you should grab the source & recompile for your system where *depends* rules don't match your *unstated* product/release.